# QML: How to select radio button from listview?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have next listview component:

CustomListRadio.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import "."

Rectangle {
    id: radio_content
    x: 0
    y: 40
    width: 320
    height: 158
    color: "black"

    property int counter: 0
    property int savedIndex: 0
    property int checkedIndex: 0
    property variant internalModel

    ButtonGroup {
        id: buttonGroup
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 320
        height: 158
        model: parent.internalModel
        anchors.fill: radio_content

        delegate: RadioDelegate {

            text: modelData
            checked: index == radio_content.savedIndex
            ButtonGroup.group: buttonGroup

            font.pixelSize: 23
            font.family: "Futura Condensed"
            font.styleName: "Medium"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    parent.checked = true
                    radio_content.checkedIndex = model.index
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

RadioDelegate.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

RadioDelegate {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("RadioDelegate")
    checked: true

    contentItem: Text {
        leftPadding: control.indicator.width + control.spacing
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: "white"
        elide: Text.ElideRight
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }

    indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 30
        implicitHeight: 30
        x: control.leftPadding
        y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
        radius: 15
        color: control.checked ? "#0088FF" : "white"
        border.color: "#0088FF"

        Rectangle {
            width: 10
            height: 10
            x: parent.width / 2 - width / 2
            y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
            radius: 5
            color: "white"
            visible: control.checked
        }
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 320
        implicitHeight: 40
        color: "black"

        border {
            color: "#383838"
            width: 1
        }

    }
}
```

How add component

```
CustomListRadio {
    id: radio_list
    internalModel: msg.languageVariantList
    savedIndex: msg.language
}
```

It creates a list of radiobuttons. It works well. But, I can't select default checked radio button. Selecting a switch with the mouse, works. But from the code, at best, my solution selects the switch only if the length of the list is equal to the number of visible elements.

Comment: Provide complete qml file.

Comment: You have to clarify your question. What is _default button_ and how do you set it _from the code_? Btw, the expression `button.id` does not make sense. There is no property named `id`.

Comment: added extended code

Comment: @СергейСахно, I can't clearly understand what result you expect. Do you want to *uncheck checked **RadioButton***?

Comment: @undefined when component is created, all radio button is unchecked. I want to check any radio button on completed component. It used for settings parametrs, and needed show start cheked radiobutton.

Comment: @СергейСахно, could you provide values of `msg.languageVariantList` and `msg.language`.
**EDIT**
And explain, what's **RadioDelegate.qml**?

Comment: @undefined, yes. msg.languageVariantList is QStringList - property from C++ code.

Comment: @СергейСахно, please read my comment carefully.

Comment: @undefined, RadioDelegate.qml provide custom component (RadioDelegate) for ListView. I found with solution on qt site, when search method of realization list of radiobutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in **RadioDelegate.qml**, need to remove next string:

```
checked: true
```